# Warning message in Bluetooth: TIOCGSERIAL is not supported

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, bluetooth, serial-port

I want to link a Bluetooth barcode scanner (Gryphon GBT4400) in "client" mode to a Bluetooth-enabled PC with the serial port profile.
The Bluetooth PC adapter is Atheros Communications AR3012.
PC is running under Ubuntu Server 16.04.

I first run the following commands through bash script:

```
    sdptool add --channel=22 SP > /dev/null
    rfcomm watch /dev/rfcomm0 22 1>/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Then with scanner I scan the barcode to link the scanner to the PC in Bluetooth (this barcode includes the MAC address of the Bluetooth interface of the PC).
It works well: PC and scanner are now connected.

Then I open the serial port through a QT/C++ application running on PC, built with QT 5.5.1, with following code:

```
    pSerialPort = new QSerialPort("/dev/rfcomm0");
    pSerialPort->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
```

At this step, this warning message is immediately displayed on PC:

```
    Bluetooth: TIOCGSERIAL is not supported
```

**Except this warning**, everything works very well: the QT application retrieves correctly all the scanned barcode values.

I found almost nothing on the web.
Can someone help me to understand this warning message ?

Comment: This ioctl is called to get stuff like baud rate that you don't care about if you don't have a real serial port.  Since its a warning, ignore it.

Comment: @stark Thanks. Even if I have to ignore it, the problem is still its occurrence on the screen that can be confusing. Could I remove it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could remove all warning and error messages with:

```
qt_app 2>/dev/null
```

but that would hide other warnings that you might want to see.  To hide just this one without having to change any source code and recompile, you can do:

```
qt_app 2>&1 | grep -v TIOCGSERIAL
```